# JSDoc type name for ES6 iterables

Tags: javascript, annotations, ecmascript-6, jsdoc, iterable

I have a javascript method that takes an iterable, i.e. any object that follows [the es6 iterable protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols). I want to annotate this in its JSDoc. How do I refer to the 'iterable' type?

```
/**
 * @param {__WHAT_GOES_HERE__?} iterable
 */
function consume(iterable) { ... }
```

I could write out the whole protocol in JSDoc, but that gets a bit... incredibly unwieldy:

```
 * @param {
 *   {
 *     Symbol.iterator: function(): {
 *       next: function() : {
 *         value: T|undefined,
 *         done: boolean
 *       }
 *     }
 *   }
 * } iterable
```

Also, tools don't seem to understand what `Symbol.iterator` means.

Comment: I usually just put `Iterable.<number>` or whatever type, but then again we don't actually generate docs from the JSDocs.

Comment: @loganfsmyth I use webstorm and it does some rudimentary type warnings based on the annotations. When I just lie about the type, it complains.

Comment: @Strilanc: What type system are you using? Can you declare interfaces there?

Comment: @Bergi The question refers to JSDoc, but my specific case is "whatever's built into WebStorm". Probably some adhoc combination of existing standards including JSDoc and Closure's type annotations.

Answer (score 1):

My current workaround solution is to define `Iterable` and `Iterator` classes with the appropriate methods. I put the classes in a location that's visible to the editor but not actually used, so the linter can see the definitions but they aren't included as bloat in the actual output.

Then, in the JSDoc of methods that take/return sequences, I can refer to `Iterable<T>` and `Iterator<T>`.